# Does cable awg/amps matter for power adapter

Tags: power-supply, cable, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I bought a longer cable for my surface pro 3 power adapter, the cable that goes from the outlet to the brick, and I noticed that the power adapter says it takes an input of 1A and the 22 awg cable says 2.5A on it. My question is, does any of that matter? or can you plug any cable into the power adapter and be fine as long as it fits?

Answer (score 0):

The cable rating means it can handle *up to* 2.5A. Your power adapter only pulls 1A. So, it's fine.

Just FYI, the connectors at the non-wall-end of disconnectable power cables are usually, these days, "IEC 320" (short form of "[IEC 60320](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320)") connectors.